# How do I remove second row from the column name in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

[image]

How do I remove the row that says "UN member states"?

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `droplevel` to completely remove a multi-index level:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)
```